# вопрос WaitForSingle для процесса

Tags: winapi

можно ли исходя из данного кода сделать вывод что процесс запущен?

```
    res = WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 2000);
    switch(res)
    {
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT: 
        //процесс не работает
        CloseHandle(hProc); //закрываем 
        return 1;
    default:
        //процесса нет
        CloseHandle(hProc);         
        return 0;
        break;
...
```

Comment: Используется для ожидания завершения работы процесса. Например мы запустили внешний конвертор видео, и надо дождаться пока он отработает. Можно запускать какие-то внешние утилиты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос - нет нельзя, WAIT_TIMEOUT означет что процесс работает.
Данная функция WaitForSingleObject используется для синхронизации с другим процессом (в данном случае), её нужно использовать, потому что при "прямом" опросе процесса у вас ЦП улетит в 100% и процессор будет греться.
Пример - можно конвертировать видео внешней утилитой и ждать её завершения. Можно выполнять какие-то действия командной строки. Можно запускать какую-либо внешнюю программу. Любую программу.

Есть стандартный пример
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes

```
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
```

В большинстве случаев этого достаточно.
CloseHandle - не закрывает процесс, а закрывает связь через которую можно взаимодействовать с процессом.

WaitForSingleObject - для процесса, она будет ожидать завершения работы процесса.
Но... если не стоит INFINITE то после ожидания процесс может ещё работать.

```
WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 2000);
```

Если вернулся WAIT_TIMEOUT, то процесс ещё работает (ну если после получения ответа мы недолго ждем), если нет - то процесс завершил работу либо невалидная hProcess.

Дальше можно строить по разному программу. Если нужно что бы процесс через 2 секунды был прерван то пишем

```
res = WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 2000);
if (res == WAIT_TIMEOUT){
   if (!TerminateProcess(hProcess , 0)) err = GetLastError();
  }
```

На прерывание чужих процессов нужны дополнительно разрешения, на дочерние доп-разрешение не нужно как правило.

Но... можно например раз в секунду сделать некоторые действия и продолжить ожидание.
Например

```
int seconds = 0;
while (running) {
   res = WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 1000);
   if (res == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
       // процесс ещё работает, отработал 1 секунду
       seconds++; 
       continue; 
       }
   // Процесс уже не работает
   break;
   }
```

Полезная функция GetExitCodeProcess

```
function isWorking(HANDLE hProcess) {
DWORD code;
if (GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess,&code)) {
      // если code - валидная
      // если code = STILL_ACTIVE = 259 - то процесс ещё незавершон
       if (code == 259) return true;
      }
  return false;
}
```

позволяет однозначно понять завершился процесс или нет

Можно так же опрашивать другие параметры процесса при работе, и так же можно взаимодействовать с консолью дочернего процесса если она есть.

Comment: а если процесс создан так : HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, ... это накладывает какой то отпечаток на то что вы ответили раньше?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что функция ожидания тормозит поток в котором вызывается на указанное время?

Comment: разъясните для чего процесс открывается с SYNCHRONIZE? Написано к этим правам доступа: Необходимо, чтобы ждущий процесс завершил работу, используя функции ожидания. Т.е получается в том процессе в котором я вызываю функцию ожидания, этот процесс должен и завершится? А кто тогда выполнить код ниже по программе, хотя бы выход из той функции в которой я все это вызываю?